# SpringData PageImpl totalElements is wrong

Tags: spring-data

When I new a PageImpl Object like :

```
new PageImpl<CompanyEntity>(content, new PageRequest(page, size), total);
```

the result is not correct.

When the "size" lagger than "total" the totalElements use the "content.size" and when "size" less than "total" the totalElements use the "total".

why ?

The "totalElements" shouldn't represent the total count of elements ?

Help!

Answer (score 4):

set `PageRequest` page start to 0. It solved my problem.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNo-1,pageSize,sort);
    Page<T> response = new PageImpl<>(result,pageRequest,totalCount);
```

Comment: What is ```result```?

Answer (score 0):

i saw the source of "PageImpl" and fond that :

```
this.total = !content.isEmpty() && pageable != null && (long)(pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize()) > total?(long)(pageable.getOffset() + content.size()):total;
```

is that right ? why `(long)(pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize()) > total?(long)(pageable.getOffset() + content.size()):total`?

Comment: I have also the same problem. Idon't know if this is a release problem, because a few weeks ago it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true
```

Without this property, the default page size starts from 0 and that would mess up all of the calculations.